# Timer stops working after 20min in webservice

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

I think my timer stops working after some time, I meassured 20min just now and havnt found anything else that causes the stop so far. If its garbage collected, how should I declare it so that it isnt?

```
[WebMethod, SoapHeader("spAuthenticationHeader")]
public void startStreaming()
{
    if (Globals._streamTimer == null)
        Globals._streamTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(handleStream, null, 0, 30000);
        return Globals._returnValue;
}


public static class Globals
{
    public static System.Threading.Timer _streamTimer = null;
}
```

Comment: Whats the session time set to on the server?

Comment: IIS has an Idle Timeout setting on the App Pool (Advanced Settings) that defaults to 20 mins...coincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your IIS settings - 20 minutes?

Web applications are not supposed to be long-running. Whatever you are doing, you should do it differently. Perhaps a Windows Service, or persistent storage and polling...

Or, you can kludge it and increase the time-out value.

[image: IIS Idle Time-out]

Comment: Did not know that. Are there any dangers with setting the time-out to 0 and letting it run "forever"?

Comment: Yeah. You can deplete the available threads in the ASP.NET thread pool. Threads are created to service a request then run forever. If you have memory leaks or allocate objects the memory is never released. If the application crashes the process is never killed. It's really a bad model that you are building. Consider a different model. Not sure what you are doing as no one would wait 30 minutes for a web response. Likely, you are wanting a web request to trigger something later. This would probably be correctly handled with a Windows Service or some other design.

Comment: Most likely, your ASP.NET service should signal a separate Windows Service (or place an item in a database) when an event occurs. The database might implement a 'trigger' which would inform the Windows Service, or the Windows Service might simply poll the database at regular intervals. The long-running Windows Service would then operate a timer or use simple polling to check the clock, and then perform whatever action after 30 minutes has elapsed. For enterprise critical needs, persistent storage like a database would be a necessity so that a reboot would not prevent the action from occurring.

Comment: Yes that is what I did to replace the webservice. And its up and running fine now. Thank you.