# Timer is getting terminated atlest once, how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I am having a timer class which runs another controller at particular interval and posts data to website. But atleast one packet is missing per day, At irregular intervals. How to avoid this data miss?

Initially i stored when the controller is executed, when it is not. It issued an error, "remote host closed the connection". I started verifying whether the timer is executed or not by keeping a log of time and if there is any error, it logs the exception and time.

Briefly,
I tried logging error if it goes to catch block, but it is not even going to on timed event or timer class.The try block in onTimedEvent stores when the timer is executed, catch block stores error in a txt file.

```
public class BaseTimer : Timer
{
    public BaseTimer(double Interval) : base(Interval) { }
    public Timer_class masterDataObj { get; set; }
}

public class Timer_class
{
    private static BaseTimer aTimer;

    public Timer_class()
    {
            double refreshTimeInterval = 5 * 60 * 1000;
            // Create a timer with a 5 minute interval.
            aTimer = new BaseTimer(refreshTimeInterval);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.masterDataObj = this;
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {           
        try
        {
            //write time when timer is triggered in timelog folder
            string dbPath = "D:\\IIS Applications\\EAS_Wattics\\logs\\";//System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dbPath + "Energy_meter_Timelog");
            string FilePath = dbPath + "Energy_meter_Timelog//P" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")  + ".txt";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
                file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                file.Close();
            }
            string result = EAS_Wattics_PostingController.post_to_wattics();
            string pbi = EAS_Wattics_PostingController.pushToPBI();
            //string missed_data = EAS_Wattics_PostingController.missed_data_post_to_wattics();
            string res_test = testController.post_to_wattics();
        }
        catch (Exception tmrEventExp)
        {
            string remark = "error :" + tmrEventExp;
            //write error and time of the error in errorlog folder
            string dbPath = "D:\\IIS Applications\\EAS_Wattics\\logs\\";//System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dbPath + "Energy_meter_Errorlog");
            string FilePath = dbPath + "Energy_meter_Errorlog//P" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy") + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") +  ".txt";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
                file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + remark);
                file.Close();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception occurred @Timer Event - Master Data Updation due to " + tmrEventExp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send data for every 5 minutes(code is in controller) but this timer class is getting terminated atleast once.

Comment: Not clear, if the issue is 'Remote Host closed...' It's nothing to do with the Timer, It executed, the web server went wrong (or net work). Could go for a retry on that sort of error, depends on how critical the five minutes is.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider using a decent logging framework.

Comment: If your website is not being constantly used, IIS will recycle the thread pool. Then your timer will not run at all (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12386151/11683).

Comment: Website is constantly used. There is no issue in that. @GSerg

Comment: What might be the reason if web server or network went wrong. How to avoid that?

Comment: In addition to what @GSerg said: By default, de Application Pool also recycles after 1740 minutes, regardless of usage. When that happens, session states are transferred to the new pool, but running threads are terminated.

Comment: If that is the issue, I have another controller which posts same data to other website which don't include timer. But the other one is working fine. Why this issue persists while using timers?